# How to create unique nodes with multiple relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 4 tables covering data on property transactions.

- Transaction table contains transactionID, price, date
- House table contains transactionID, adress
- Buyer table contains transactionID, name, dateOfBirth
- Seller table contains transactionID, name, dateOfBirth

A house may have changed hands several times. A person may be listed in both the buyer and seller tables for different transactions. A transaction may have multiple buyers and/or sellers.

My aim is to create three nodes labelled :People, :House and :Transaction with their relevant relationships. i.e. the :People and :House nodes will point to the :Transaction nodes.

My issue is in how to create unique :People nodes with the different transactions they are involved in.

I am a complete novice and this is the first (non-tutorial) graph I have set up. I have tried various methods using MERGE to no avail. Below is some starter code-

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///...transactions.csv" AS row

CREATE (:Transaction {transactionID: row.transactionID, price: row.price, date: row.date});

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///...house.csv" AS row

CREATE (:House {transactionID: row.transactionID, address: row.address});

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///...buyers.csv" AS row

CREATE (:Person {transactionID: row.transactionID, name: row.name, dOB: row.dateOfBirth});

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///...sellers.csv" AS row

CREATE (:Person {transactionID: row.transactionID, name: row.name, dOB: row.dateOfBirth});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach.

1. Create all `Transaction` nodes:

   ```
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///...transactions.csv" AS row
   CREATE (:Transaction {transactionID: row.transactionID, price: row.price, date: row.date});
   ```
2. Create `House` nodes (if not already existing), and connect each to the proper `Transaction` node (but ignore rows with `transactionID`s having no `Transaction` nodes):

   ```
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///...house.csv" AS row
   MATCH (t:Transaction {transactionID: row.transactionID})
   MERGE (h:House {address: row.address})
   CREATE (h)<-[:HOUSE]-(t);
   ```
3. Create `Person` nodes (if not already existing) for the buyers, and connect each to the proper `Transaction` node (but ignore rows with `transactionID`s having no `Transaction` nodes):

   ```
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///...buyers.csv" AS row
   MATCH (t:Transaction {transactionID: row.transactionID})
   MERGE (p:Person {name: row.name, dOB: row.dateOfBirth})
   CREATE (p)<-[:BUYER]-(t);
   ```
4. Create `Person` nodes (if not already existing) for the sellers, and connect each to the proper `Transaction` node (but ignore rows with `transactionID`s having no `Transaction` nodes):

   ```
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///...sellers.csv" AS row
   MATCH (t:Transaction {transactionID: row.transactionID})
   MERGE (p:Person {name: row.name, dOB: row.dateOfBirth})
   CREATE (p)<-[:SELLER]-(t);
   ```

NOTE: With this approach, multiple `Person` nodes can have the same `name` value (as long as they have different birthdays). You may wish to give each `Person` a unique `id` to distinguish between them.